# Expecting 'STRING', got 'undefined' in request response

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm using requests module in order to interact with an API:

```py
response = requests.get(<URL>)
my_dict = response.json()
```

`my_dict` var looks something like this (I've simplified the dict) :

```json
{'annotations': 'list'}
```

The problem is that the response doesn't pass the json linter due to `Expecting 'STRING', got 'undefined'`, I'm assuming that it single quote `'` generates this problem .

Any ideas how to fix this ?

UPDATE:

Grafana upload (actually I'm using the API, but the result is the same GUI or API)

Also jsonlint throws the same error: https://jsonlint.com/

[image]

Comment: Did this happened to all websites? If not, please include on which websites you face the problem

Comment: Question updated. Thx

Comment: my_dict is a Python dictionary, not JSON. That's why it has single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.json()` actually parses the response. Since that returns successfully, you already know it's valid JSON. If it weren't valid, you'd have to fix the code of the API your accessing

If you only want the JSON response body, use `response.text`

Comment: Daaam you're right thx man and actually I had it initially  `response.text` for string and `response.content` for bytes  but I went for response buit-in `response.json()` in order to avoid doing each time `json.loads(response.text)`